# Javascript: Find the Parent Element Text

Tags: javascript, selenium, kendo-grid

How do I find the Parent Attribute for a data-element (data-qa). I have a data attribute id, data-qa=productId1  , productid2, productid3.  (for each row in the grid)

For each row number in a grid.

How do I tell if the parent Element has kendogridcell above?

I don't know what kendogridcell is, its not a class.

```
let dataQaElements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-qa]`);

for (let i = 0; i < dataQaElements.length; i++) {
  let attr = dataQaElements[i].parentElement;
  // not sure what next code is
}
```

[image]

Currently team is doing Selenium test automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dataQaElements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-qa]`);

for (let el of dataQaElements) {
  const parent = el.parentElement;
  const kendogridcell = parent.getAttribute("kendogridcell"); // if exists "" or null if does not exist
}
```